# How right ad image in div who have resizable()?

Tags: jquery, resizable

Good day.

I would like add image in div who have class

Code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".resizable").resizable();
});     
</script>


<div class="resizable" id="photo">
  Resizable
</div>

$('#photo').html('<img src="./Images/Temp/' + data + '"/>');
```

But when i add image with help jquery div ceases to stretch

Please tell me was error or no ?

Answer (score 1):

call `resizeable` again when you make the changes

```
$('#photo').html('<img src="./Images/Temp/' + data + '"/>').resizable();
```

Comment: bipenm i check with firebug, bt not see errors...all html here http://pastebin.com/3M00xudq

Comment: sorry, now up i add rows. please see code again here http://pastebin.com/pbcXntYG